# Minimizing WPF Window when pressing <Windows button> + <M>

Tags: wpf, windows, c#-4.0, wpf-controls

I have a WPF application and I want to make it minimize by pressing <kbd>Windows button</kbd>+<kbd>M</kbd> just like any normal window. How can this be done?

Comment: Are you hiding the normal titlebar or doing anything non-standard? I just ran a WPF app and minimized with the rest of the windows like it should.

Answer (score 0):

Since you've not provided much information, I can only guess as to why your window is not minimizing. My guess is that you have set [`ResizeMode`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.window.resizemode.aspx) to `NoResize`.